# Websocket client messages

Tags: python, websocket, streaming

I've set up a websocket in order to receive real-time messages from the Benzinga news API and although things seem to be set up, I am consistently receiving messages like :

send: b'\x8a\x80E\x9c\x8f\x1a'
send: b'\x8a\x80\xc3(\x19\x12'
send: b'\x8a\x80e\x19\x8d\x16'
send: b'\x8a\x80\\xd9\xfbn'
send: b'\x8a\x80##\xfa\x15'

What do these messages mean please? And are these messages of a nature which allows me to decode them into human- readable form? The code:

```
def on_message(ws, message):

msg = json.loads(message)
# print('Generic===================================')
# print(msg)
# print('Generic===================================')
try:
    if len(msg) > 0:
        if msg[0] and 'msg' in msg[0] and msg[0]['msg'] == 'authenticated':
            ws.send(json.dumps({"action":"subscribe","news":["*"]}))
        if msg[0] and 'headline' in msg[0]:
            headline = msg[0]['headline']
            symbols = msg[0]['symbols']
            print('Source===================================')
            print(headline)
            print(symbols)
            print('Source===================================')
            data = {'headline': headline.lower(),'symbols': symbols}
```